# ActiproSoftware controls breaks Moq unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

Moq does not want to work with ActiroSoftware on net core 3.1

I'm having the following issue: creating a net core 3.1 project with the following structure:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.14.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Actiprosoftware.Controls.WPF" Version="20.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

then in Program.cs try to write the following:

```
using Moq;

namespace moqtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var q = It.IsAny<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this won't compile, due to the following error:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IsAny' does not exist in the namespace 'It' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Furthermore, specifying the namespace implicitly, will work:

```
var q = Moq.It.IsAny<string>();
```

I have looked into msbuild diagnostics and it seems everything is compatible with netcoreapp3.1, but when you compile it, it seems it does not recognize **It** class anymore.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up `View > Object Browser`, and search for `It`. You'll notice that first result is a **namespace** called `It` brought in by `ActiproSoftware.BarCode.Wpf.dll`

It also happens to be an empty namespace, but that's irrelevant. If it did contain anything under it, you'd refer to them as `It.Something`. So what happens now is that, even after you  do `using Moq`, `It` is still ambiguous to the compiler.

The presence of that silly empty namespace is what's forcing to qualify your calls with `Moq.`

Comment: I knew those Actipro guys screwed it up, cause it did show as a namespace when i was typing something. Thank you so much!